# Android: will system stop unbound service if it's running in foreground?

Tags: android, android-service

The application uses bound service. So, the service is NOT started using startService anywhere. Every activity which needs to access the service binds to it using bindService.

In some situations service is going foreground (with startForeground).

In particular there might be a situation when nothing is bound to service (which, according to the doc means that service will be stopped) but it's running in the foreground (which means that it wont' be stopped). Which of those rules have priority? Will system stop unbound service when it's running in foreground?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In some situations service is going foreground (with startForeground).

This is not particularly useful, as the process will already be in the foreground, because the activity using the service is in the foreground.

> Which of those rules have priority?

The service will be destroyed after the last client has unbound from it. `startForeground()` does not impact this.

Comment: i don't think i understand you. service indeed goes foreground by some action triggered from activity, which is itself in foreground. however, service is intended to keep running when activity goes background - until it's explicitly stopped by user. so, i need to ensure that service won't be killed by system. according to the docs startForeground doing this job for me.

Comment: @Alex: Quoting the documentation: "A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API". You are not starting a service -- you are binding to a service. Quoting the documentation: "thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory". Your service is not going away due to low memory -- it is being destroyed because all bound clients unbound from it and you failed to call `startService()`.